# How to activate the buttons in a Tableview of BSP application (SAP)

Tags: crm, sap-bsp

In a Bsp application i need to activate and make these buttons of a tableview work,currently the buttons are present and part of the layout, but they dont work,anyone has any idea how i could make them work?The buttons that i need to activate are maximize,minimize,standard etc.

Thanks in advance,
Shamiron

Comment: "but they don't work" --> Please add an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question. Without it, it's impossible to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code for button, there itself you can resize the button

```
<Input Type = 'Submit'  ... >
```

I think in that you didnt mention **event handler** tab section.

```
<input type=submit name="onInputProcessing(back)" value="home">
```